# Javascript number guessing game - setting up the counter & while loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a random number guessing game in Javascript that compares user input to a number generated with the math.random method. I'm confused by how to set up the counter the right way. I have to validate the number, display each guess with "too high," "too low" or "you win" then show the 'secret' number at the end. Not sure what I'm doing wrong! Right now it is overwriting each answer and the counter is staying at #5.

```
function myFunction() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("text").value;
    // test for valid input number from 1 to 999 
    if (userInput < 0 || userInput > 999) {
         alert("Your number must be from 1 to 999");
    } else {
        alert("Input OK");
    } // end function myFunction

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()* 999)+1;
    var userInput = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var counter = 0;
    var totalGuesses = 0;
    while (totalGuesses <= 5) {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById('loopResults').innerHTML = "<p>You have made" + counter + "guesses</p>";
      if (userInput < randomNum) {
          document.getElementById('loopResults').innerHTML += "<p>Your guess is too low!</p>";
      } else {
          document.getElementById('loopResults').innerHTML += "<p>Your guess is too high!</p>";
      } 
   }
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Guessing Game</h1>
<p id="loopResults"></p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="userData">
    <input name="userInput" id="text" type="text" size="10" /> - &nbsp;Enter a number from 1-999!</form>
    <p><span style="background-color:#066aff; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px;" onclick="myFunction();" >enter number</span>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have both `counter` and `totalGuesses` variables? Looks like you'll have an endless loop because you never increment `totalGuesses`. Also you never test if the current guess is correct, you only check if it is too low and otherwise assume it is too high. Also the user never gets a chance to change their guess.

Comment: The problem is your `while loop` does not depending on click event, so it is constantly running. You should put `counter++;` and `totalGuesses++` inside click handler, and check for `totalGuess` not be higher than 5

Comment: I think that's where I'm getting confused...that should probably be totalGuesses++. This is way over my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `while loop` here. What happen is simply once it enters the while loop, it increments your `counter` to 5.

Take the `while loop` out and it will do what you want it to do.

And I don't think you need the `totalGuesses`

**Edit:**

So I further look into your code. In order to do what you want it to do, instead of putting everything in your `myFunction`, here are the steps:

1. create a `random_number`
2. create a `counter`
3. a function that is bind to `onclick`, this is where the main logic is. And here's what you need to do.

   1. get the input result from the input field, and parse it to `Integer`
   2. compare with the stored `random_number`
   3. if correct, alert ok
   4. if not, increment the `counter`
   5. if the `counter` reaches limit, alert and show result

Not going to write down the code, and I think you can figure it out.

Comment: itsgoingdown - when you say inside click handler, do you mean onclick="myFunction(counter++); ?